# Css : divs alignment in div

Tags: html, css

My 2 secondary div don't want to be at the center of the primary.
I have this code :

HTML:

```
<div id="body">
 <div id="content">
  <div id="contact">
     <div class="contact">
        <img id="contact_photo" src="images/contact_photo.png">
     </div>
     <div class ="contact" id="contact-text">
          some text<br>
          some text<br>
          some text
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#body{
  background-image: url("../images/background_body.png");
  height : 100%;
  width:101%;
  margin : 10px -10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content{
  color: white;
  padding: 0 0 0 395px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 26px;
}
#contact{
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: white;
  width: 1035px;
/*  background-color: green;*/
  display: flex;
  padding: 35px 80px 0 80px;
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact{
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}

#contact-text{
  width: 385px;
  height: 145px;
}

#contact_photo{
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

If someone can help me, I saw everywhere that they centered the div only with :

```
text-align: center;
```

and

```
float: none;
display: inline-block;
```

I don't find what's the matter.

Thank you

Comment: Try `.contact { margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: Ok ! thank you it work, but I don't understand why I need that !

Comment: Elements can either be block or inline. An inline element will be centered by `text-align: center;`, however block elements (like `<div>`) will *not*. Instead, you can center a block element by giving it a horizontal-margin of `auto`. This only works if the element has a defined width, the element is *not* floated, the element is not `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;`, and the element is `display: block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.contact {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This makes the margins on right and left sides set to the same so that the item will be displayed in the center;